# Frobenius algebra structure over complex polynomials modulo $x^2$.

Tags: coalgebras, frobenius-groups, coproduct

I was trying to define a Frobenius Algebra structure over complex polynomials modulo $x^2$, but I am really struggling to do so.
The algebra structure is rather evident, but I've tried many possible coproducts without success so far.
My intuition tells me that the counit linear map will send every polynomial to its evaluation on $x=0$ (so the free coefficient), and I tried defining the coproduct as

$$\Delta(f(x)) = f(x) ⊗ 1(x) + 1(x) ⊗ f(x)$$

It does give me a coproduct structure, but it fails to work on the Frobenius structure, since it doesn't make the diagram below commute (at least the lower triangle doesn't commute).
Is there any known Frobenius structure for this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this as an old question, but I figured I would answer it for posterity.

I think you are approaching this wrong, what you are describing is the comultiplication that will give you a Hopf algebra structure. For a Frobenious structure, the counit should be the Frobenius form you want in your algebra. In this case needs to be
$$\varepsilon(x)=1\hspace{1cm} \text{and}\hspace{1cm} \varepsilon(1)=0$$
so that the kernel doesn't have any nonzero ideals.

From this you obtain that the comultiplication
$$\Delta(1)=1\otimes x+ x\otimes 1\hspace{1cm} \text{and}\hspace{1cm} \Delta(x)=x\otimes x$$

In fact, the complex polynomials modulo $x^2-t$ will have Frobenius structure given by this same counit/Frobenious form and the comultiplication
$$\Delta(1)=1\otimes x+ x\otimes 1\hspace{1cm} \text{and}\hspace{1cm} \Delta(x)=x\otimes x+t 1\otimes 1$$